# How can I get the raw body from a REST endpoint in Hasura?

Tags: hasura

I'm trying to set up a webhook using Hasura's REST interface. I want to just accept any data that's sent to the webhook without validation.

Is it possible to do something like this:

**REST endpoint**

```
http://localhost:8080/api/rest/callback
```

**Methods available**

```
POST
```

**GraphQL Request**

```
mutation MyMutation ($rawBody: String!) {
  myMutation(payload: $rawBody) {
    mutationResult
  }
}
```